# Magento 2 How to create another group like the Related Products one?

Tags: magento2, group

I'm using Magento 2 and I'm trying to create another group, like the related products one , so when I'm on the product page , and I slide to bottom , I'm able to see both groups, Related products on one row , and my second group , is that possible to do ?

Answer (score 0):

There is [Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts](https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts) module available for adding custom product links but unfortunately its for magento version 1, I guess you can get an idea of the flow from this and convert it to magento 2 relevant code